# Is there any significant overhead to running Google Clouds Tasks (e.g. push queues)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-tasks

Is there any significant overhead to running Google Clouds Tasks (e.g. push queues)?

For example, will there be more overhead computational cost if you have one Task that does 10 operations in it (for example, making 10 calls to the Datastore) versus if you have 10 Tasks where each task does 1 of the same operation? All other things being equal of course.

Recently in the news Amazon Prime Video showed how it saved a lot of money by moving off of serverless architecture. In a way, Cloud Tasks are a bit like serverless so I am curious if they could become expensive in a similar way.

Is there a way to calculate the above costs in my application?

Comment: That was a clickbait news article without any substance.  Serverless didn't work for them because they had a bad design.  It works great when designed well.

Comment: This is not an opinion based question. This is a question of how Cloud Tasks work technically and the cost of them. Please re-open.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **complex**.

---

If you use Cloud Functions and one task uses XX CPU cycles, have 10XX cycles on 1 function, or 10 functions of XX cycles is strictly the same. Roughtly

Indeed, if you go in the detail, on Cloud Functions the billing is at upper bound of 100ms. Therefore,

- if your task take 20ms to complete, if you run the 10 tasks on the same Cloud Functions, it will take 10x20 -> 200ms of billed CPU
- If you have 10 functions that run 20ms, the cost will be 100ms for each function, and there 1000ms for the 10 tasks, 5 time more.

*That difference can be ignore is the tasks take many seconds to complete*

---

I can continue in that headache and blur more the things! If you use Cloud Run, you process the tasks concurrently with the same instance (CPU and memory).

At the opposite of the Cloud Functions where (with gen1) 1 instance (CPU + memory) is created for each process (each task)

In that situation, there is 2 cases:

- Your process is CPU intensive and the concurrency on the same instance makes no sense (you can't share a CPU use at 100%!), and 1 instance per task is better
- Your process wait most of the time (typically when you perform an API call, the process wait a lot (50 - 200ms) the API answer. While the process wait, another things can be performed, like processing the other tasks and generate also API calls (or process the response when receive). With that configuration you could increase the whole latency, but clearly reduce the cost.

---

Another parameter to take into account is the "intro" and "outro" of the functions

Take this design:

- init something
- perform the task(s)
- format and send the answer.

Here again, if the "init" and the "format answer" take lot of CPU cycles, and there is no real differences if there is 1 or 10 tasks performed in the middle, it's a clear advantage to group the tasks in a same function.

At the opposite, if they are not relevant, it's "equal" (according to my description before).

---

One size does not fit all!! And the best choice depends on your app design and behavior! That's the real job of a cloud architect!